# Regex for customer/order number extraction from URL

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url, trim

I am hoping a regex guru can help to solve my issue,

I want to search the following `URL's` to extract certain pieces of data:

- `/#!/customers/2848060/orders/9234573/history`

  1. I want one regex function to extract the number following `'customers'` string `(2848060)`.
  2. I want another regex to extract the number following the word `'orders'` `(9234573)`.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you play around with https://regex101.com/ to build your regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

> I want one regex function to extract the number following 'customers'
>   string (2848060).

```
/(?<=customers\/)(.*)(?=\/orders)/g
```

> I want another regex to extract the number following the word 'orders'
>   (9234573).

```
/(?<=orders\/)(.*)(?=\/history)/g
```

Following is snippet for test

```js
var str = '/#!/customers/2848060/orders/9234573/history'

var customer = str.match(/(?<=customers\/)(.*)(?=\/orders)/g)[0]
var order = str.match(/(?<=orders\/)(.*)(?=\/history)/g)[0]

console.log(customer);
console.log(order);
```

**Alternative Solution**

> I want one regex function to extract the number following 'customers'
>   string (2848060).

```
/customers\/(.*)\/orders/
```

> I want another regex to extract the number following the word 'orders'
>   (9234573).

```
/orders\/(.*)\/history/
```

Following is snippet for test

```js
var str = '/#!/customers/2848060/orders/9234573/history'

var customer = str.match(/customers\/(.*)\/orders/)[1]
var order = str.match(/orders\/(.*)\/history/)[1]

console.log(customer);
console.log(order);
```

Comment: JS doesn't support lookbehinds in regular expressions, only lookaheads

Comment: May be my knowledge regarding RegEx is limited. Could you please point me in a direction where your comment is explained. Thankyou.

Comment: the `(?<=...)` part is not allowed/supported in JS. That's why your snippet throws an Error

Comment: @Thomas this is exactly what I need, am I correct in saying this will not be supported in JS then (?<=customers\/)(\d+), if not are you aware of any alternatives for look behinds?

Comment: Added an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I want one regex function to extract the number following 'customers'
>   string (2848060)

Use *capturing groups*

For *customer*  `/customers\/(\d+)/`

```
var matches = "/#!/customers/2848060/orders/9234573/history".match( /customers\/(\d+)/ );
if (matches)
{
   console.log( "customers " + matches[1] );
}
```

> I want another regex to extract the number following the word 'orders'
>   (9234573).

Similarly for *orders*  `/orders\/(\d+)/`

**Also, you may not need regex** if you URL pattern is likely to be the same

```
var items = str.split( "/" );
var customers = items[4];
var orders = items[6];
```

Comment: Thanks! I originally was using split however the URL could or could not have the orders part of the URL. Meaning it could be /customers/17264658 only.

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = /\d+/g;
var s = "/#!/customers/2848060/orders/9234573/history";
var m;
while ((m = r.exec(s)) != null) {
  alert(m[0]);
}
```